# php artisan route list

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 7.  I am trying to run the `php artisan route:list`.
When I run the command above I get this:

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\PhotosstarsController] does not exist.
> at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:811
> 807|
> 808|         try {
> 809|             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
> 810|         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
> 811|             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
> 812|         }
> 813|
> 814|         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
> 815|         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

Laravel is right it does not exist. Where is Laravel getting the information from?

I believe that this is affecting my routes because when I want to delete it goes to a blank page.

Comment: you have a route in your any of the routes file which is using the missing controller. find out which one and you can then resolve this.

Comment: If it is not required PhotostarsController comment out the relavent route list

Comment: I can't comment it out there is no such controller

Answer (score 0):

not sure, but also check the namespace specified in RouteServiceProvider.php and that controller namespace